# MySQL Query to calculate average price until stock value reaches 0

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables which I would like to use but unfortunately this question exceeds my knowledge.

First table shows the stock I have with product ID and Quantity

```
id    PID   Quantity
1      5       8
2      45      7
3      125     0
```

The second table stores my purchase orders I did to purchase the products I have in stock.

```
id      Date      PO ID    PID    Price    Purchased Quant.
1       1.1.19    PO1      5      8.00     7
2       1.1.19    PO1      45     2.15     9
3       2.1.19    PO2      5      4.45     6
```

As a result I would like to get the average price per `PID` caclulated from the latest purchase date.

```
PID    Average Price
5      5.3375
45     2.15
```

For `PID` '5' I have 8pcs in stock and I find 6 pcs purchased on 2.1.19 for 4,45€. Therefore I need to find another 2 pcs in an older purchase which I can find on 1.1.19 for 8.00€.

```
Average price calculation -> (6pcs * 4.45€ + 2pcs * 8.00€)/8pcs = 5.3375€
```

For PID 45 the calculation should be the same however my stock is completely fulfilled with the first PO.

Is there any way I can solve this in MySQL with a query.

Comment: Which MySQL version do you have? `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Version 5.6.38-nmm1-log

Comment: Sorry Raymond I don't understand what you exactly mean. The price of 5.3375€ should be right as a result. I have only 8 pcs of PID "5" in stock. The last time I purchased 6pcs of this article for 4.45€. So I have only 2 pcs left which could not be calculated with my latest purchase price. Therefore I need to find my second latest purchase in which I purchased this product to also fulfil my remaining two pcs with the price of 8.00€

Comment: Ah here we go. The second table is not what I sold but what I purchased.

Comment: Right i linked purchased to the word sold, i think i need to fully wake up and get some (very) strong coffee before helping others on stackoverflow i geuss..

Comment: Don't worry. Your help is always appreciated

Comment: Can you explain me how it's possible to get the `2pcs` in the Average price calculation for PID 5? Because ` Purchased Quant.` is `7` and `6` for PID 5

Comment: Just look from today backwards (today = 24.2.19) so the latest purchase for PID 5 was made on 2.1.19. with a quantity of 6 pcs. Therefore take the full 6 pcs purchased on 2.1.19 for calculation. So you just need to find a second latest price for the remaining 2 pcs.

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY on you second table?

Comment: Nothing yet. I will built the tables myself so can still do adjustemnts if necessary.

Comment: In an RDBMS, a table is not really a table until it has (at least) one way of uniquely identifying rows.

Comment: I have edited my question and added a unique id to the tables.

Comment: What I do not understand is why you say in one table that you have 8 products #5, but in your purchase table you have adquired in total 13 products #5?

Comment: @ Carlitos. The first table is my stock which I have. The second table is the goods which I purchased. For ID 5 this would mean that I have sold 5 pcs in the meantime. So I purchased in total 13 pcs sold 5 thats why I have 8 left.

Answer (score 0):

In versions of MySQL before 8.0 this is not easy to achieve. You can do it with the use of variables that change during the execution of the query, but be aware that there is no documented guarantee that the order of variable assignment is as might be expected.

Now that I have given the disclaimer, here is the query you could use:

```
select   pid,
         sum(price * take)/sum(take) avg_price
from     (
          select   pid,
                   price,
                   @quantity := if(@pid = pid, @quantity, available) needed,
                   least(@quantity+0, quantity) take,
                   @quantity := @quantity - least(@quantity, quantity),
                   @pid := pid
          from     (select     o.*, 
                               p.quantity available 
                    from       orders o
                    inner join products p
                            on p.pid = o.pid
                    order by   o.pid,
                               o.date desc) data,
                   (select @pid := -1,
                           @quantity := 0) vars
          order by   pid, date desc) base
group by pid
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRKQfJmkEnSpBYL51gzFku/0)

For a more reliable way, you would better migrate to MySQL where you can use window functions.

Comment: Or MariaDB 10.2.